# Passing additional attributes all the way thru to nested serializers

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I've been having issues passing additional attributes thru using Django Rest Framework with nested serializers.

I've created a **Document** model that has a ForeignKey **owner**/creator relationship, and several other ForeignKey related models. Some of those other model have an **owner**/creator ForeignKey associated as well.

```
class Document(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',related_name='document')
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(
                                  Candidate,
                                  on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                  blank=True,
                                  null=True,
                                 )

class Candidate(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='candidates')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
```

When saving down the **Document** model with a nested serializer and a custom `create()` method, I can pass all fields down, however, the nested models don't seem to be able to pick up the Owner field, regardless of how I pass it in. Creating a Candidate alone is fine.

```
class CandidateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
     class Meta:
        model = Candidate
        fields = (
              'pk',
              'first_name',
              'owner',
              )

class DocumentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    candidate = CandidateSerializer(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        fields = (
                  'owner',
                  'candidate',
                  )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        candidate_data = validated_data.pop('candidate')
        document = Document.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Candidate.objects.create(**candidate_data)
```

With **DocumentSerializer** set up like this, I get errors like this while trying to do a POST to Document with nested fields.

```
IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: dossier_candidate.owner_id
```

When I modify the `DocumentSerializer.create()` method to try to pick up the owner, it seems that `owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')` is now out of scope, even though it should be under the class.

i.e.,

When I try to create the Candidate object with

```
Candidate.objects.create(owner, **candidate_data)
```

I get this error :

```
NameError at /rest/documents/
global name 'owner' is not defined
```

When I try this

```
Candidate.objects.create(self.owner, **candidate_data)
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DocumentSerializer' object has no attribute 'owner'
```

What's the proper method of making sure the nested Candidate object is able to be created successfully, picking up the owner field?

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, you won't have the owner to create/update since it's read only.

If you want to get the current user for that, use [CurrentUserDefault](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault). It'll be added to the `validated_data`